# Making a 3D model in VTK solid instead of hollow inside

Tags: python, vtk, volume-rendering

I'm trying to create 3D model of the skull using VTK [example]:(https://kitware.github.io/vtk-examples/site/Python/VisualizationAlgorithms/HeadBone/)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import vtkmodules.vtkInteractionStyle
# noinspection PyUnresolvedReferences
import vtkmodules.vtkRenderingOpenGL2
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonColor import vtkNamedColors
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonCore import (
    VTK_VERSION_NUMBER,
    vtkVersion
)
from vtkmodules.vtkCommonDataModel import vtkMergePoints
from vtkmodules.vtkFiltersCore import (
    vtkFlyingEdges3D,
    vtkMarchingCubes
)
from vtkmodules.vtkFiltersModeling import vtkOutlineFilter
from vtkmodules.vtkIOImage import vtkMetaImageReader
from vtkmodules.vtkRenderingCore import (
    vtkActor,
    vtkPolyDataMapper,
    vtkRenderWindow,
    vtkRenderWindowInteractor,
    vtkRenderer
)


def main():
    # vtkFlyingEdges3D was introduced in VTK >= 8.2
    use_flying_edges = vtk_version_ok(8, 2, 0)

    file_name = get_program_parameters()

    colors = vtkNamedColors()

    # Create the RenderWindow, Renderer and Interactor.
    ren = vtkRenderer()
    ren_win = vtkRenderWindow()
    ren_win.AddRenderer(ren)
    iren = vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(ren_win)

    # Create the pipeline.
    reader = vtkMetaImageReader()
    reader.SetFileName(file_name)
    reader.Update()

    locator = vtkMergePoints()
    locator.SetDivisions(64, 64, 92)
    locator.SetNumberOfPointsPerBucket(2)
    locator.AutomaticOff()

    if use_flying_edges:
        try:
            using_marching_cubes = False
            iso = vtkFlyingEdges3D()
        except AttributeError:
            using_marching_cubes = True
            iso = vtkMarchingCubes()
    else:
        using_marching_cubes = True
        iso = vtkMarchingCubes()
    iso.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())
    iso.ComputeGradientsOn()
    iso.ComputeScalarsOff()
    iso.SetValue(0, 1150)
    if using_marching_cubes:
        iso.SetLocator(locator)

    iso_mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    iso_mapper.SetInputConnection(iso.GetOutputPort())
    iso_mapper.ScalarVisibilityOff()

    iso_actor = vtkActor()
    iso_actor.SetMapper(iso_mapper)
    iso_actor.GetProperty().SetColor(colors.GetColor3d('Ivory'))

    outline = vtkOutlineFilter()
    outline.SetInputConnection(reader.GetOutputPort())

    outline_mapper = vtkPolyDataMapper()
    outline_mapper.SetInputConnection(outline.GetOutputPort())

    outline_actor = vtkActor()
    outline_actor.SetMapper(outline_mapper)

    # Add the actors to the renderer, set the background and size.
    #
    ren.AddActor(outline_actor)
    ren.AddActor(iso_actor)
    ren.SetBackground(colors.GetColor3d('SlateGray'))
    ren.GetActiveCamera().SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
    ren.GetActiveCamera().SetPosition(0, -1, 0)
    ren.GetActiveCamera().SetViewUp(0, 0, -1)
    ren.ResetCamera()
    ren.GetActiveCamera().Dolly(1.5)
    ren.ResetCameraClippingRange()

    ren_win.SetSize(640, 480)
    ren_win.SetWindowName('HeadBone')

    ren_win.Render()
    iren.Start()


def get_program_parameters():
    import argparse
    description = 'Marching cubes surface of human bone.'
    epilogue = '''
    '''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description=description, epilog=epilogue,
                                     formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument('filename', help='FullHead.mhd.')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args.filename


def vtk_version_ok(major, minor, build):
    """
    Check the VTK version.

    :param major: Major version.
    :param minor: Minor version.
    :param build: Build version.
    :return: True if the requested VTK version is greater or equal to the actual VTK version.
    """
    needed_version = 10000000000 * int(major) + 100000000 * int(minor) + int(build)
    try:
        vtk_version_number = VTK_VERSION_NUMBER
    except AttributeError:  # as error:
        ver = vtkVersion()
        vtk_version_number = 10000000000 * ver.GetVTKMajorVersion() + 100000000 * ver.GetVTKMinorVersion() \
                             + ver.GetVTKBuildVersion()
    if vtk_version_number >= needed_version:
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It appears that model works just fine, but there is something that I want to know. The model of the skull works perfectly fine, but the model density is not solid (it hollow inside). It generates only the surface of the model.

I want to know how I can fill the gap in the surface to get the full solid model.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you are trying to extract the isosurface (hollow) from the data.
`vtkFlyingEdges3D()` and `vtkMarchingCubes()` algorithms will create contours based on the `iso.SetValue(0, 1150)` and extract the surface for you. If you want to keep it filled, remove the contouring functions, i'e, `vtkFlyingEdges3D()` and `vtkMarchingCubes()` from your script and use some image data mapper instead of vtkPolydataMapper, it will show the entire object.